# "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.nodeType')" in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have the following code in my phantomjs script:

```
var page = new WebPage(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;


    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    };

    page.onLoadStarted = function() {
      loadInProgress = true;
      console.log("load started");
    };

    page.onLoadFinished = function() {
      loadInProgress = false;
      console.log("load finished");
    };



    var steps = [

    function() {

        console.log("Load Login Page");
        //spoof user-agent
        page.settings.userAgent = "'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';";
        page.open("https://login.XXX.com");

      },
```

Initially this seemed to be working. Now I am getting the following error and the login is not working:

```
"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.nodeType')".
```

Has anyone come across this? Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do : check the source of this error.

Something which was not clear for me when I started in PhantomJS, is that by default "errors" contains your script compilation/execution errors and also page javascript errors.
Especially, you have a callback on onConsoleMessage, so maybe the error is coming from the target page.

Basically, when there is an unhandled error, PhantomJS enters an invalid state and execution stops.

You have add an handler to [webpage.onerror](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) on [phantom.onerror](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html).

Comment: Thanks Cybermaxs, That is very useful info. I have been trying to debug mainly by trial and error.